# Upgrading R to 3.6 - utils package cannot be loaded

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to upgrade R from 3.4.4 to 3.6.0 on a rather old ubuntu xenial version.

I followed these instructions: [here](http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/)

Here are the steps I took:

1. sudo apt-get remove r-base-dev
2. echo 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty-cran35/' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

My R version updated to 3.6, however, whenever I start R in console I get the following messages:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘utils’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: file(con, "r")
  error: cannot open the connection
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: file(con, "r")
  error: cannot open the connection
During startup - Warning messages:
1: In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/etc/os-release': Permission denied
2: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
3: In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/etc/os-release': Permission denied
4: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

This is the output of /etc/os-release. I did chmod to 666, but nothing changed.

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Here is my libPaths' output.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/myuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

I cannot install any packages in R. Any help will be appreciated.

FYI - There is an rstudio server installed on the machine which I havent touched at all.

Comment: I assume you haven't upgraded to a new version of Ubuntu because it isn't your machine?

Comment: yes, you are right. This is a company server, I somehow happened to work on :)

Comment: What's the output of `ls /etc/os-release -li`?

Comment: @duckmayr here it is: `1845913 -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 249 Aug  1  2016 /etc/os-release`

Comment: How bizarre. I don't have a fix (yet?), but here is what's happening: In `.onLoad()` for `utils`, [`.osVersion()` is called](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d6c208e464d20adc6ce080ecfaaab4ccf3f06271/src/library/utils/R/zzz.R#L53). `.osVersion()` [attempts to read /etc/os-release](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d6c208e464d20adc6ce080ecfaaab4ccf3f06271/src/library/utils/R/sessionInfo.R#L33), and in your case, has trouble opening a connection to the file.

Comment: yep, that is how far I got from the message, and that was why I `sudo chmod 666 /etc/os-release` .. did not help though :( .. trying to install R from source now .. see if that helps. Will keep you updated. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Yeah, installing from source was going to be my next suggestion. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I did the following:

1. Uninstalled previous version - `sudo apt-get remove r-base-dev`
2. Downloaded from source - `wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.6.0.tar.gz`
3. Followed these instructions [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218004217-Building-R-from-source)
4. After setting path, I started R, and it was still not working, however I realized it was looking at `/usr/bin/R` which for some reason might have not been the correct binary to use.
5. I deleted this file and created a symlink to the fresh installation - `sudo ln -s /opt/R/3.6.0/bin/R /usr/bin/R`
6. Then it worked like a charm.

FYI - during the previous steps I had stopped rstudio-server just in case it is not keeping any files locked. I restared it afterwards and it is all fine.

Comment: Congrats on getting it sorted!

Comment: Thanks, man! It is good to know that there is someone out there who is always willing to help!